# What's the alternative of Listagg in Netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza, group-concat, listagg

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLE_A WHERE DATE >= CURRENT_DATE;
```

The output for the above query will be

```
001
002
003
```

I need the output as 001,002,003. I am trying below in Netezza but GROUP_CONCAT is not installed in database. This could be easily done in ORACLE using Listagg. But the group_concat & string_agg not working for me.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID,',') 
FROM (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_A WHERE DATE >= CURRENT_DATE) a;
```

Please help if we can do something only with normal sql without using any function.

Comment: If you dont have group_concat installed, you could follow this to install group_concat.  https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datamanagement/discussion/looking-for-the-source-code-for-the-group-concat-udf

You could also raise an IBM support ticket.

Comment: Shekars solution is the best for sure, but a similar function (with a looong name I cannot remember) is installed if you have the ‘R’ functions installed, and the XML functions can be ‘hacked’ to do the same (I tried both). Furthermore the ARRAY functions can bring you close.

Comment: This isn't the option I have. Anything else with replace() kind of function we can do?